# Xzing barcode : I'm getting type mismatch error in fragment using androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin, zxing

I'm using Android studio 4.0, coding in Kotlin and I'm still really new at Android development.I need to integrate the Xzing barcode libray. I've copied some code from the tutorial at [https://tutorialwing.com/implement-android-qr-code-scanner-using-zxing-library-in-kotlin/][1]. The tutorial uses the following import statement:

```
import android.app.Fragment
```

I've modified a fragment that was generated with the Navigation Drawer Activity template. It uses the androidx fragment import statment:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
```

The errors it occurs on the following line with the "this" reference:

```
qrScanIntegrator = IntentIntegrator.forFragment(this)
```

The error is:

```
Type mismatch: Required Fragment! found HomeFragment
```

Changing my import to the older version to the older version is not recommended and if I do I get a lot of other errors.

What can I do to get zxing to work with the androidx fragment?
Thanks

Comment: Can't you pass your activity instead of the fragment?

Comment: I have a main_activity with all of the ui views in fragments with viewmodels and live data. I need to hook up the scanner with one of the fragments. Could I use pass my main_activity to run zxing?

Comment: Also would Zxing work with androidx when call from an activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ZXing library is no longer maintained, and that particular class ([`IntentIntegrator`](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android-integration/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java)) only supports `android.app.Fragment` which is the deprecated Android framework version of the AndroidX `Fragment` class.

You have a few possible options here:

1. Fork the ZXing library, and change the `android.app.Fragment` import to use the `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` version instead.
2. Delegate the `IntentIntegrator` calls to your `Activity` instead, and have the results forwarded to your `Fragment`.
3. Simply duplicate the `Intent` [initialization code](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android-integration/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java#L299) from `IntentIntegrator` to a helper class of your own. The `IntentIntegrator` methods are just convenience methods to build an `Intent` and call `startActivityForResult()`. You'll still be able to use the `IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult` method to interpret the result that comes back.

I would recommend going with option #3.

As a longer term alternative, you may also want to consider looking into [Firebase ML Kit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/read-barcodes) since ZXing is no longer maintained.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I'm looking at the Google Vision barcode api, which predates the Firebase ML Kit. It seems simpler than the Firebase ML Kit implementation. But nothing is decided yet.

Comment: I've implemented the Google Vision barcode api which does solve the problem so I'll mark this as answered.